# Remove the command line prompt from results of the babel's shell code

Tags: emacs, org-babel

Upon running commands on org's babel source code

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :session hugo :results output
hugo new posts/my_first_post.md
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: /home/me/Documents/quickstart/content/posts/my_first_post.md created
: (base) [01;32mme@alpha[00m:[01;34m~/Documents/quickstart[00m:
```

There's a prompt suffix appended `: (base) [01;32mme@alpha[00m:[01;34m~/Documents/quickstart[00m:`

Other examples

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :session hugo  :results output
cat ./content/posts/my_first_post.md 
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: ---
: title: "My_first_post"
: date: 2019-09-06T13:46:46+08:00
: draft: true
: ---
: 
: (base) [01;32mme@alpha[00m:[01;34m~/Documents/quickstart[00m:
```

How could remove the suffix by configure the babel' header arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest might be just to set your prompt, `PS1` in your initial code block.  Org-babel does attempt to clean the prompt with `org-babel-sh-strip-weird-long-prompt`, but it doesn't appear easily customizable.  So, you could just use

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :session hugo :results output
PS1="> "
echo
#+END_SRC
```

Since you're using `:session` you should only need it in your initial block.

Note: it looks like this should only be an issue when using a session, since the shell isn't run through comint otherwise